# How to show KUSER_SHARED_DATA members in decompiled C code?

Tags: windows, decompilation, ghidra, hexrays

Here is a sample C code which prints Windows version directly from address
of [KUSER_SHARED_DATA](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/structs/kuser_shared_data/index.htm). Tested in Windows 10 only. The raw memory address
differ in Windows version but that's not the point.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    wprintf(
        L"Version: %lu.%lu.%lu\n",
        *(unsigned int *)(0x7FFE0000 + 0x026C),
        *(unsigned int *)(0x7FFE0000 + 0x0270),
        *(unsigned int *)(0x7FFE0000 + 0x0260)
    );
}
```

Here are the decompiled code:

In GHIDRA:

```
int main(int _Argc,char **_Argv,char **_Env)

{
    wprintf(L"Version: %lu.%lu.%lu\n",
        (ulonglong)_DAT_7ffe026c,
        (ulonglong)_DAT_7ffe0270,
        (ulonglong)_DAT_7ffe0260);
  return 0;
}
```

In IDA Pro + Hex-Rays:

```
int __fastcall main()
{
    wprintf(L"Version: %lu.%lu.%lu\n",
        MEMORY[0x7FFE026C],
        MEMORY[0x7FFE0270],
        MEMORY[0x7FFE0260]);
  return 0;
}
```

My question: In decompiled code, is it possible to show the memory address as
the member of KUSER_SHARED_DATA? For example, I want to show `MEMORY[0x7FFE0260]`
as `SharedData.NtBuildNumber` or something similar to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For IDA/Hex-Rays:

1. In the Loaded Type Libraries window (`View->Open subviews->Type libraries`), load `ntddk_win10` (or whatever Windows version you want, back to Windows XP and Windows Server 2003).

[image: Available Type Libraries]

2. In the Structures window (`View->Open subviews->Structures`), import `KUSER_SHARED_DATA`. You can simply write the name of the type in the dialog box and press OK, as in the following image:

[image: Create structure/union]

3. Under `Edit->Segments->Create segment`, create a new segment with that memory range, as in the following image.

[image: Create a new segment]

4. At the beginning of the new segment, use `Edit->Struct var`, and select `KUSER_SHARED_DATA`.

[image: Choose a structure type]

That's it. Now the disassembly listing looks like this:

[image: Disassembly]

And the decompilation looks like this:

[image: Decompilation]

Comment: You could write a script to do all of that automatically if you wanted to. Is it really worth the effort, however? It took less than two minutes to do it. Unless you're doing it very frequently for some reason, I personally don't see the point in investing the effort into writing a script. As for whether there's one command to do all of that, why on earth would there be? What would you propose for the name of that command?

Answer (score 3):

ghidra

```
addr = toAddr(0x7ffe0000)
currentProgram.memory.createUninitializedBlock("KUSER_SHARED_PAGE",addr,0x1000,0)
createData(addr,getDataTypes("KUSER_SHARED_DATA")[0])
```

result

```
undefined8 main(void)

{
  wprintf((__crt_locale_pointers *)L"Version: %lu.%lu.%lu\n",
          (ulonglong)KUSER_SHARED_DATA_7ffe0000.NtMajorVersion,
          (ulonglong)KUSER_SHARED_DATA_7ffe0000.NtMinorVersion,
          (ulonglong)KUSER_SHARED_DATA_7ffe0000.NtBuildNumber);
  return 0;
}
```

**Method 1)**

Use VirtualQuery to get the size
shown below is a python poc
compare the result to (MEMORY_BASIC_INFO *)foo.RegionSize

```
:\>cat vq.py
from ctypes import *
meminfo =(c_ulong * 0x8)()
windll.kernel32.VirtualQuery(0x7ffe0000,byref(meminfo),sizeof(meminfo))
for i in meminfo:
    print (hex(i))


:\>python vq.py
0x7ffe0000
0x7ffe0000
0x2
0x1000
0x1000
0x2
0x20000
0x0
```

**Method 2)**

use windbg !vprot to get the same

```
:\>cdb -c "!vprot 7ffe0000;q" cdb | awk "/Reading/,/quit/"
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '!vprot 7ffe0000;q'
BaseAddress:       7ffe0000
AllocationBase:    7ffe0000
AllocationProtect: 00000002  PAGE_READONLY
RegionSize:        00001000
State:             00001000  MEM_COMMIT
Protect:           00000002  PAGE_READONLY
Type:              00020000  MEM_PRIVATE
quit:
```

**Method 3)**

use windbg !address to Get a more Verbose Details of the same Address Space

```
:\>cdb -c "!address 7ffe0000;q" cdb | awk "/Usage:/,/quit/"
Usage:                  Other
Base Address:           7ffe0000
End Address:            7ffe1000
Region Size:            00001000 (   4.000 kB)
State:                  00001000          MEM_COMMIT
Protect:                00000002          PAGE_READONLY
Type:                   00020000          MEM_PRIVATE
Allocation Base:        7ffe0000
Allocation Protect:     00000002          PAGE_READONLY
Additional info:        User Shared Data


Content source: 1 (target), length: 1000
quit:
```